# javascript hangs browser

Tags: javascript, browser

```
xmlDoc.load("cd_catalog.xml")

var cd=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
var id_set=1;
var id=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ID"+id_set);

i=0;

function next()
{
if (i<id.length-1)
  {
  i++;
  display();

  }
}


function display()
{
document.write('<div class="dd">')
        document.write('<div class="blue" style="WIDTH:')
        document.write(cd[0].getElementsByTagName("ID"+id_set)[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
        document.write('"></div>')

document.write('</div>')

}


}
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> display()   </script>


    <br><input type="button" onclick="next()" value="next" ID="Button2" NAME="Button2"/>
```

I saw [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575222/newbie-hanging-browser-on-function-call), but not sure that helps..
I added the next() function and the browser hangs as if it is loading something, never does.
Without the next() call the display function works. I am trying to do a variation [of this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_app_navigate).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That [related queston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575222/newbie-hanging-browser-on-function-call) *does* help.  You can't use `document.write()` after the document has finished loading.  See the answer to that other question for how to replace `document.write()`.