# Simple bookmarklet creates endless loop

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, bookmarklet, document.write

This book-marklet:

```
javascript:document.write('hello world');
```

creates an endless loop when you click on it.  Or so I guess, as that browser tab correctly displays hello world, one time, but the busy indicator is always present.

Comment: Works fine for me in Safari on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add *document.close();* to stop the "hanging" in Firefox.

```
javascript:document.write('hello world');document.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

See this related question:
[Newbie: hanging browser on function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575222/newbie-hanging-browser-on-function-call)

The document.write() function causes issues if used after the page has completed loading. If you're looking for a simple proof-of-concept option, I would recommend using alert() instead.